# How to receive a text stream in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I have a barcode scanner which automatically outputs the barcode into whichever app you have open in the USB attached windows PC, if it can handle it. For example if I have chrome open, I click the address bar and then scan it outputs to there. Similarly if I click on a website textarea and then scan it'll dump it in there.

I have a simple flutter application which I simply want to detect the scan receival. I don't care how, but I don't even know what exactly to search for to get my answer. My aim is to have a windows app in flutter, which when I scan a barcode it receives this, displays the product details in the flutter screen (aka needs an API call straight after getting the scan). Any help on even what topic to search for will help, cheers.

Barcode scanner: Symcode MJ-340 Automatic Desktop USB Wired Barcode Scanner.

Comment: Maybe this package could help you: https://pub.dev/packages/barcode

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I worked out that a common way to interact for barcodes through USB to apps is via the USB HID aka keyboard presses. By wrapping the app around a RawkeyboardListener with autofocus true, you can filter via RawKeyUpEvent (or down) and then simply set the state.

In my case, it always ended with an enter key to detect the end of a code.

Comment: Hi, fred. I was actually building a windows pos application. So far, this post is one of the few resource I've found. Can you share some code snippets please? I have no idea how to start this project.